# Ex.11 Sec.I-4 Conway's Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, nets

The following is from chapter 1, section 4 of Conway's A Course in Functional Analysis, second edition: I tried a lot but have no idea how to solve it :

> If ${\{h_n}\}$ is a sequence in a Hilbert space and $ \sum_{n =1}^{\infty} \left\lVert h_n \right\rVert < \infty$ show that
> $ \sum {\{h_n : n \in F}\}  $ converges as a net.

Please see details of definition and similar problem from the book [in here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459094/net-convergence-and-norm-convergence-in-hilbert-spaces).

A hint also would be much appreciated.

Comment: Show that $s_N=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N h_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. The limit is thus the candidate for the limit of the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea:

note that from the finiteness of the sum $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\|h_n\|$ it is true that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a natural number $N_{\varepsilon}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n\geq N_\varepsilon}\|h_n\|< \varepsilon.
\end{equation*}

Now, to prove the claim it suffices to show that the sequence is Cauchy.
For every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a finite set $S:=\{1,\dots,N_\varepsilon\}$ such that for every couple of finite sets $F,F'\supseteq S$ we have
\begin{equation*}
\left\| \sum_{n\in F}h_n - \sum_{m\in F'}h_m \right\| = \left\| \sum_{n\in F \setminus (F \cap F')}h_n - \sum_{n \in F'   \setminus (F \cap F')} h_n\right\| \leq  \sum_{n\geq N_\varepsilon} \|h_n\| < \varepsilon,
\end{equation*}

Comment: Why is $\sum_{n \in F} h_n - \sum_{m \in F'} h_m = \sum_{n \in F \triangle F'} h_n$?

Comment: I think this does not hold in general.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, that equality is not true, I'm sorry. I edited the answer.